# Gstreamer get image width and height

Tags: png, gstreamer, libpng, python-gstreamer, java-gstreamer

I have a simple gstreamer pipeline which looks like :

| Filesrc | --> | PngDec | --> | ImageFreeze | --> | Queue | --> | Compositor | --> | Fake Sink |

`location` (input) of the filesrc is a png file of size 400 X 600.

In the pipeline how do I get the width and height of the file? (400 X 600)

Comment: You check caps between connections and read out the widht and height fields.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch - Thanks a lot for the suggestion and checking the caps does reveal the image dimensions.

Comment: Well depends between which elements you check and what you do. That is how elements know about dimensions too..